# How can I copy a BigQuery dataset from one region to another?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to copy a dataset `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales` from the US to the EU.

But `bq cp` doesn't work between regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BigQuery Data Transfer Service.

First, create the destination dataset:

```
bq mk --location eu ch10eu
```

Then, create a transfer config whose data source is cross_region_copy:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --data_source=cross_region_copy \
   --params='{"source_dataset_id": "iowa_liquor_sales", "source_project_id": "bigquery-public-data"}' \
   --target_dataset=ch10eu --display_name=liquor \
   --schedule_end_time="$(date -v +1H -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)"
```

Because the data transfer service is meant for routine copies, this will repeat every 24 hours. In my example, I **set the end time to be 1-hour from now**, so that the transfer happens only once.

Comment: Use `date --date "+1 hour" -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ` if you have Linux or GNU date (instead of BSD date).

Comment: And you need to enalbe the BigQuery Data Transfer service here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com .
Read: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/enable-transfer-service